# combobox returning null value in c#

Tags: c#, for-loop, combobox, null, return-value

Here I created a for loop to list a range of numbers from 1 to 30 in the comboBox, but when I try to display the selected item from the combobox into a MessageBox it returns a null value. How can I get it to return the number selected from the comboBox? Here is my code:

```
    string selectedNumber;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
        {
            string[] numbers= { i.ToString() };
            comboBox1.Items.AddRange(numbers);
        }

        selectedNumber = comboBox1.SelectedText;

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(selectedNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: because there is no text selected

Comment: try `MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedText);`

Comment: @Sayse Note that OP doesn't select any item, so reading `SelectedItem` also wont help

Comment: There is nothing selected in the ComboBox when you assign it to `selectedNumber` - so there is nothing to show.  Also, build your array in the loop, and then assign the array to the combobox *after* the loop is complete.

Comment: When I use SelectedItem I get 2 erros saying:
"The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(string)' has some invalid arguments"
and
"Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'"

I also tried MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedText); but I still get a null value.

Comment: @meau94 - is the ComboBox's DropDownStyle set to `DropDownList`?  If so, `SelectedText` will return an empty string.

Comment: Your code is correct (according to your question), It will show the selectedtext, Your mistake is thinking that there is a selection. By default, there isn't any item selected when you create a combo box.

Answer (score 2):

Reason is clear that you have no text selected

You've to select any item in combobox first. To do so try any of the following

1. Set `SelectedIndex` to some valid index
2. Set `SelectedItem` to a valid item in combobox through code
3. Select an item in combobox by clicking it

Then use following code

```
MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedText); or

if(comboBox1.SelectedItem != null)//check for null since `SelectedItem` can be null when nothing selected
    MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

Note: As @tim pointed in comments `SelectedText`  approach won't work when `DropDownStyle` set to `DropDownList`. In that case you've to use `SelectedItem` approach

Answer (score 1):

As several have pointed out, there is nothing selected in the `ComboBox` when you assign `SelectedText` to `selectedNumber`.  I would try two things:

First, don't call `AddRange` every time through the loop - build the array in the loop and then once the loop exits you can use `AddRange`.  I would also use a `List<string>`:

```
List<string> numbers = new List<string>();

for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
{

    numbers.Add(i.ToString());
}

comboBox1.AddRange(numbers);
```

Secondly, in your button click event, show the selected text:

```
MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedText);
```

If `comBox1`'s DropDownStyle is set to `DropDownList`, `SelectedText` will give an empty string.  In that case, something like this might help:

```
MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

In reality, you'd probably want to handle the corresponding selection changed event for `ComboBox` as you'd probably want to do something with it in your program, but it looks like you're just trying some things out right now.

**Edited To Add**

Note that as Sriram said, `SelectedItem` can be null, so you'll want to check for that condition with either Sriram's or Przemyslaw's code if you're using `SelectedItem` instead of `SelectedText`.

Answer (score 1):

Here, with null check:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItem = comboBox1.SelectedItem ?? "";

    MessageBox.Show(selectedItem.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Bad place to use the null coallesce operator in my opinion, why would you want to show an empty message box?

Comment: Well, of course you can change empty string to something like "No item selected". I feel like coalescing operator works like charm here.

Comment: I don't think coalesce operator is good idea when you deal with different types. Here `Object` and `String`. If both are same type I agree with you.

Comment: Yes, for that you're of course right, it's not a VERY good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can try this

```
                for (int x = 0; x <= 30; x++)
                  comboBox1.Items.Add(x.ToString());
```

I find it a lot simpler